# $sformatf in SystemVerilog is not printing Hyperlinks on stdout

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

The output of this SystemVerilog code should print hyperlinks on `stdout` that are not appearing, but it is capturing those hyperlinks in the file.

```
module top;
string res="some string";
string id="ID1";
string name1="Ram";
string name2="Singh";
string filename="test.sv";
int line=3;
string verbocity="High";
int fd1;

initial begin
res=$sformatf("<message ctxt=\"%s\" kind=\"%s\" id=\"%s\" location=\"%s:%0d\" verbosity=\"%s\" time=\"%0t\">%s</message>\n",name1,name2,id,filename,line,verbocity,$realtime,res);
$display(res);
fd1 = $fopen("data_txt", "w");
$fwrite(fd1, "%s\n", res);
$fclose(fd1);
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simulator should show the formatted string on `stdout`.  Since it does not, there is a bug in the simulator you are using.

For example, with Synopsys on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/wGKj), I see the following on `stdout`:

```
<message ctxt="Ram" kind="Singh" id="ID1" location="test.sv:3" verbosity="High" time="0">some string</message>
```

However, with Cadence, I see:

```
some string
```

This is the original value of `res`, without the formatting.  This is a bug in the Cadence simulator.  Three other simulators show the formatting (Synopsys, Mentor, Aldec).